# How to properly change href attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change `href` attribute of a link `.filter` on mouseover. The link has a `data-href` attribute that contains partial string that is to be merged with another partial string contained somewhere else, and placed as value of `href`.

The outcome I am getting from the below script is nothing happens on the mouseover. When I move the mouse over the element second time, new updated URL appears in the status bar.

```
$('.filters-nav .filter:not([data-href=""])').on( 'mouseover' , function() {

    var href = $(this).parents('.filters-scroll').attr( 'data-base' );

    $(this).attr( 'href' , href + $(this).attr( 'data-href' ) );

    $(this).attr( 'data-href' , '' );

    //return false;
});
```

How to change URL on the first mouseover. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QAwF/1/)

I am using Firefox 27.*

Comment: I suspect the URL is actually changing the first time you mouseover, but you don't see the new href in the status bar until the second time.

Comment: No, its not. When I click on the link, the previous partial is opened.

Comment: Have you tried `mouseenter`?

Comment: Checked. `mouseenter` too doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post your html too? Most useful if you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: [This](http://jsbin.com/vogemamo/1/edit) worked for me (Chromium 25.x). But it didn't work with Firefox. I guess some sort of caching is the cause.

Comment: How many `.filters-scroll` elements exist in the `$(this).parents('.filters-scroll')` result?

Comment: @Derek there is only one `.filters-scroll` in parents.

Comment: @Unknown posted jsfiddle. Check question.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour http://jsbin.com/vogemamo/1/edit not working here :( it now seems to be a browser issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yZ2fN/

Comment: @HamidSarfraz At first hover, I got `http://example.com/mytag` and then every time `http://example.com`. Is this not the expected output ?

Comment: @Derek alert box is showing correct URL. Can anyone confirm that the problem relates to firefox only? I have tried my site and the jsfiddle i posted above on Chrome, and both work perfectly fine. But not in firefox.

Comment: @HighBoots Yes it is the expected output. I have found that the original script I posted and the one other friends posted work in Chrome, but not in Firefox 27. It may be a bug or something.

Comment: @HamidSarfraz check my answer below, it works for me in FF 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `prop()` method for setting the 'href' property instead of `attr()`.

```
$('.filters-nav .filter').one('mouseover',  function() {
    var href = $(this).closest('.filters-scroll').attr('data-base');
    $(this).prop('href', href + $(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

The `one()` method adds an event which is triggered once and is automatically removed. This way you don't have to use a complicated selector.

See my JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yZ2fN/, just remove the alert calls and you should be good to go. Works in latest FF.

Comment: Why would this solve the particular issue the OP mentions where they don't see anything happen the first time.

Comment: same result with `prop` :(

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, or post a jsfiddle with it? Could be your DOM isn't as you're expecting. What happens when you do a `console.log($(this).prop('href'));` after you set the new `href` property?

Comment: @Derek Suppose the two chunks of text that I merge and place as `href` are `http://example.com/something/` and `mytag`. This script is now showing correct URL in status bar, but on click, I am taken to `http://example.com/mytag' instead of `http://example.com/something/mytag`. This was not the original problem that I requested a solution for, but infact arises as a result of this answer. Any idea?

Comment: @Derek checked this in FF and Chrome.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to work fine in FF 27. See http://jsfiddle.net/yZ2fN/1/ . Really not sure why you're having such difficulty when everyone else's works. make sure you clear your cache i guess.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Its working now. The problem was mainly caused by FF's behaviour, and partly due to my mistake. Thanks for your all comments and answer @Derek.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div.filters-nav > a.filter:not([data-href=""])').on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).prop('href',$(this).parent('.filters-scroll').attr('data-base') + $(this).attr('data-href'));
    $(this).prop('data-href','');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4QAwF/7/)**

**NOTE:** Tested in FF 27.0.1 and Chrome 33.0.1750.117 m

Comment: +1 Thanks. Its working now. A little thing to mention here, `prop` is actually not for `href`, its for boolean attributes.